# How do store 3 radio button list values into mysql in a single column, different row?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, radio-button

I have 3 different radio button lists. Users can choose one value for each radio button list, and then it will store into mysql database. How do I store them in a single column, different row? Please help! Thanks.

```
//sql

$sql = "INSERT into ratings (product, rating) VALUES ('".$key."', '".."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230770/how-do-store-3-radio-button-lists-in-mysql-database-in-single-column-different

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT statement with multi insert rows.

```
INSERT INTO ratings (product, rating) 
VALUES (1, 1), 
       (1, 2), 
       (1, 3);
```

Check this link [**MySQL INSERT Statement**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

To store single or multiple choices as a single record(column) I suggest to encode the choices as an integer value.

If you had many options which are exclusive, you can encode those as integer values.

```
option1 encoded as 1
option2 encoded as 2
option3 encoded as 3
option4 encoded as 4
option5 encoded as 5
```

If you have very few and nonexclusive options you should encode them as bits in an integer:

```
option1 encoded as 1 (binary ...00001)
option2 encoded as 2 (binary ...00010)
option3 encoded as 4 (binary ...00100)
option4 encoded as 8 (binary ...01000)
```

the second representation allows you to store 2 or more choices in a single integer value:

```
option2 + opton4 encoded as 8 + 2 = 10 (binary ...01010)
(no option selected) encoded as 0      (binary ...00000)
```

More on bitvise operations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation