# How do store 3 radio button lists in mysql database in single column, different rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database, radiobuttonlist

This is my ratings.php (html codes)

```
<input type="radio" name="selectThree" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="selectThree" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="selectThree" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="selectThree" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="selectThree" value="5">

<input type="radio" name="selectTwo" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="selectTwo" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="selectTwo" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="selectTwo" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="selectTwo" value="5">

<input type="radio" name="selectOne" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="selectOne" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="selectOne" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="selectOne" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="selectOne" value="5">
```

So when users select the value, it will generate the below codes here to insert into database:

```
<?php
include_once "mysqli.connect.php";
include_once "config.php";

if(isset($_POST['Click']))      
{

$rating = explode($_POST['selectOne'], $_POST['selectTwo'], $_POST['selectThree']);
$_SESSION['commentInput'] = array();
$_SESSION['commentInput'][] = $_POST['comment'][0];
$_SESSION['commentInput'][] = $_POST['comment'][1];
$_SESSION['commentInput'][] = $_POST['comment'][2];

if(isset($_REQUEST["comment"]))
{

$merge = array_combine ($_SESSION['product'],$_SESSION['commentInput']);
foreach($merge as $key => $value)
{

$sqlComment = "INSERT into comment (comment, product) VALUES ('".$value."', '".$key."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlComment);
}

echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your comment!' )</script>";
}

else
{

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please comment!')</script>";    
}   

}
```

I want to store like this in mysql database 
->

```
product|rating
--------------
shirt  | 2
pants  | 3
dress  | 5
```

But now it stores like this:

```
product|rating
--------------
shirt  | Array
pants  | Array
dress  | Array
```

after I used this ->

```
$rating = explode($_POST['selectOne'], $_POST['selectTwo'], $_POST['selectThree']);

//mysql
$sqlRating = "INSERT into ratings (product, rating) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$rating."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlRating);
```

How do I make the values store into mysql? Please help thanks!

Comment: what is the name of your radio button?

Comment: @ianace selectOne, selectTwo, selectThree I have 3 radio button lists

Comment: is the insert query generation under a foreach loop?

Comment: @ArunKillu my key is to store the products into single column, different rows which output correctly. As for exploding, I'm trying out for my radio buttons.

Comment: @artsylar yes, i need that foreach loop to be there.

Comment: i think it's better you post your html code also

Answer (score 1):

your `$rating` is an array

you should stor values like that `$rating[0]` or `$rating[1]` or `$rating[2]` , so to store them like that u can manage them in php wich button is selected or clicked then store them in your table

Answer (score 0):

try putting it inside a foreach loop something like this.

```
// create an array here that contains the key and the rating key=>rating and save it to $ratings array.

foreach($ratings as $key=>$rating){

   //mysql
   $sqlRating = "INSERT into ratings (product, rating) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$rating."')";
   $result = $mysqli->query($sqlRating);
}
```

by the way, here's tutorial on posting radion buttons values http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html

**Update:**
Assuming that $key contains array of products. (ex. array('shirt', 'pants', 'jacket') and it is mapped to the values of the radio buttons.

```
'shirt' => $_POST['selectOne'];
'pants' => $_POST['selectTwo'];
'jacket' => $_POST['selectThree'];
```

We can create an array called $prod_ratings for $key and $ratings

```
$ratings = array($_POST['selectOne'], $_POST['selectTwo'], $_POST['selectThree']);
$prod_ratings = array_combine($key, $ratings);
```

Then insert the values of the array to the database by:

```
foreach($prod_ratings as $key=>$rating){

   //mysql
   $sqlRating = "INSERT into ratings (product, rating) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$rating."')";
   $result = $mysqli->query($sqlRating);
}
```

Comment: $key=>$rating you have to use

Comment: it shows me this error -> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: have you created the $ratings array? please post your latest code so we can help you.

Comment: where are you getting the values of $key in your post?

Comment: @artsylar $key -> product (from another php page, therefore I use session to store.)

Comment: and here's the correct usage of explode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: so how do you map the keys and the ratings? is it like $key[0] => $_POST['selectOne'] and so on?

Comment: i have updated my answer. could you please check if it answers your question?

Comment: can you print the value of your $_POST["selectOne"], etc. and your $key

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a comma-separated way using implode:

```
$rating = explode($_POST['selectOne'], $_POST['selectTwo'], $_POST['selectThree']);

//mysql
$sqlRating = "INSERT into ratings (product, rating) VALUES ('".$key."', '".implode(",",$rating)."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlRating);
```

Later on you should be able to use find_in_set to look into that column while filtering data.

Comment: Hi, it stores all the same values into database.